# Как можно поправить стили для IE8?

Tags: css

Есть сверстанный макет, который хорошо выглядит в Хроме и Мозилле, но есть недочеты в IE8. Можно написать стили для их исправления, но их надо как-то хитро подключить, чтобы в других браузерах исправления не загружались.

**Как подключить стили, что бы их видел только IE8?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

для 8 и ниже версий ИЕ

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link href="css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

для 8 версий ИЕ

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
   <link href="css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Более подробно - 
[Условные комментарии](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii)